# Complex SQL select using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Supose you have this table:

```
Name    C1   C2
Name1    A   1
Name1    B   2
Name2    B   1
Name2    A   2
```

What I need as result is:

```
Name1   B  2
Name2   B  1
```

I try

```
select Name, max(C1), max(C2) from table
group by Name
```

but it does not work,
please help.

Comment: What is the logic behind your expected resuts? How should they be calculated from your dataset?

Comment: Distinct Name, Distinct C2, Max C1

Comment: I don't understand your needed results for Name2. How is max(C2) equal to 1?

Comment: It should work `select name, max(c1), max(c2) from (
select 'name1' as name, 'a' as c1, 1 as c2
union all
select 'name1', 'b', 2
union all
select 'name2', 'a', 1
union all
select 'name2', 'b', 2
) v
group by name`

Comment: @ErickLangfordXenes . . . Your results don't really make sense.  The value "1" is never associated with "B" in your table.

Comment: Note your result is: (name1,b,2; name2, b, 2) and i want: (name1,b,2; name2, b, 1) note the last 1

Comment: You need to explain the logic more.  I can't see how you could get `Name2   B  1` out of that table either.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I've noticed now. Why the last number is 1, not 2? Explain what are you trying to fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select
    A.*
From [Table] A
Join (Select Name, MAX(C2) From [Table] Group By [Name]) B
    On A.Name = B.Name And A.C2 = B.C2
```

Comment: If you need to MAX by C1 then just specify MAX(C1) in nested query and join condition.

Comment: there is a better way? I mean, more clean?

Comment: This returns "2" in C2, never "1".

Comment: @ErickLangfordXenes what you mean by more clean? :? If it is working then there is no simpler way to get those results for sure.

Comment: And I would suggest you to use Primary Key with your table, if you clearly want to get last row for each distinct [Name] value.

Comment: Absolutely. You can not get both max values and corresponding row results in a one select.

Comment: I don't think `GROUP BY [Table]` works in MSSQL2008, did you mean `GROUP BY Name`?

Comment: @JulienBlanchard ohh, sure there has to be Name! Thanks for letting me know, will edit it right now.